# Algorithm to list all possible ways to break a number into k factors?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, multiset

As part of my effort to explore algorithms through project Euler, I'm trying to write a method that will accept an integer 'n', number of factors 'k' and factorize it. If its not possible, it will throw an error.

For instance, if I enter factorize(13257440,3), the function will return a list of all possible unique sets with 3 elements where the product of the 3 elements is equal to 13257440.

My first though is to generate a multi-set of prime factors of n (with 'm' representing the size of the set), then partition the set into k partitions. Once partition sizes are determined, I would treat it as a combinations problem.

I'm having trouble however formulating algorithms for the two parts above, and have no idea where to start. Am I over complicating a simple problem with a simple solution? If not, what are some recommended approaches? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your current code..?

Comment: the approach sounds right.

Comment: the combination part is like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30538777/2521214

Comment: Currently I've implemented a function that will return a list of primes, but have no idea where to even begin for the partitioning and combination.

Answer (score 0):

1. **primes decomposition**

   find all primes that can divide `n` without remainder. Use sieve of Eratosthenes to speed up the process considerably.

   You can use/modify mine (**warning this link is project Euler spoiler**)

   - [get primes up to n in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

   now you need to modify the code so the prime list will change to multiplicants list. For example if `n=12` this will found `{ 2,3 }` and you need `{ 2,2,3 }` so if divider prime found check it again and again until it is not divisible anymore each time lessen the `n`.

   Add a flag to each found prime (is used?) to speed up the next step...
2. **The combination part**

   I assume the multiplicants can be the same so add `k` times `1` to the primes list at start and create function that create all possibilities of numbers up to some `x` from found unused primes. Add the counter for unused primes `m` so at start the `m` is set to prime list size and the flags are all set to unused.

   Now you need to find all possibilities of using `1..m-k+1` numbers from the list. Each iteration set the picked number as used and decrease `m` so it is something like:

   ```
   for (o=1;o<=m-k+1;o++)
   ```

   here find all combination of `o` unused numbers so handle it as `o` digit number generation with base `o` without digit repetitions it is `o!` permutations.

   You can use this (**warning this link is Euler spoiler**):

   - [permutations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30498154/2521214)

   do not forget to set flag for each used number and unset it after iteration is done. Rewrite this function so it is iterative with calls `findfirst()`, `findnext()` similar to mine permutation class.

   Now you can nest all this `k` times (with use of nested `for`s from the permutation link or via recursion each time lessen the `k` and `n`)

Comment: I'm not understanding the combinations part. Are you saying to find all possible combinations of the available primes 'm-k+1' times, each time removing an element from the available set? How does that lead to all possible k factors?

Comment: @Ellyl it is just an intermediate step it will create all numbers that can be constructed from the found primes (you should ignore duplicates) so you will have k-1 such steps nested together and the last factor is what is left unused or `n/all found multiplicants` for current iteration. The point is to use only yet unused numbers to avoid many duplicates ...