# Guava Collections : limit permutation size

Tags: java, collections, permutation, guava

Using guava 12 ***Collections2.permutations()***, I'm wondering if it's possible to limit the size of the permutations ?

More precisely, I would like to get a list of k-sized permutations within a list of n elements, instead of getting a list of all n-sized permutations.

Currently, if I pass a list of 4 fruits, ***permutations()*** will currently return a list of 24 4-sized permutations although I'm only interested in retrieving, say, the 4 unique size 3 permutations.

Say I have a list of 4 fruits :

```
["Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach"]
```

If I'm only interested in size 3 permutations, I'd like the following returned :

```
["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
["Banana", "Apple", "Peach"]
["Banana", "Orange", "Peach"]
["Apple", "Orange", "Peach"]
```

Could anyone please provide any hints to a solution ? Thanks !

Comment: `Collections2.permutations(coll).filter(l -> l.size() == k)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code works out the variations, then runs the permutations on each unique set of 3.

i.e. for "A", "B", "C", "D" the possibilities are [[A, B, C], [A, B, D], [A, C, D], [B, C, D]]. We then calculate the permutations on each threesome (or n-some) and append the possibilities to a list.

**PermutationsOfN.processSubsets( List set, int k )** returns:
[[A, B, C], [A, B, D], [A, C, D], [B, C, D]]

Taking it a bit further **PermutationsOfN.permutations( List list, int size )** returns:
[[A, B, C], [A, C, B], [C, A, B], [C, B, A], [B, C, A], [B, A, C], [A, B, D], [A, D, B], [D, A, B], [D, B, A], [B, D, A], [B, A, D], [A, C, D], [A, D, C], [D, A, C], [D, C, A], [C, D, A], [C, A, D], [B, C, D], [B, D, C], [D, B, C], [D, C, B], [C, D, B], [C, B, D]]

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class PermutationsOfN<T> {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<String> f = Lists.newArrayList( "A", "B", "C", "D" );
    PermutationsOfN<String> g = new PermutationsOfN<String>();
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=1 subsets %s", g.processSubsets( f, 1 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=1 permutations %s", g.permutations( f, 1 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=2 subsets %s", g.processSubsets( f, 2 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=2 permutations %s", g.permutations( f, 2 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=3 subsets %s", g.processSubsets( f, 3 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=3 permutations %s", g.permutations( f, 3 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=4 subsets %s", g.processSubsets( f, 4 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=4 permutations %s", g.permutations( f, 4 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=5 subsets %s", g.processSubsets( f, 5 ) ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "n=5 permutations %s", g.permutations( f, 5 ) ) );
  }

  public List<List<T>> processSubsets( List<T> set, int k ) {
    if ( k > set.size() ) {
      k = set.size();
    }
    List<List<T>> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    List<T> subset = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity( k );
    for ( int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
      subset.add( null );
    }
    return processLargerSubsets( result, set, subset, 0, 0 );
  }

  private List<List<T>> processLargerSubsets( List<List<T>> result, List<T> set, List<T> subset, int subsetSize, int nextIndex ) {
    if ( subsetSize == subset.size() ) {
      result.add( ImmutableList.copyOf( subset ) );
    } else {
      for ( int j = nextIndex; j < set.size(); j++ ) {
        subset.set( subsetSize, set.get( j ) );
        processLargerSubsets( result, set, subset, subsetSize + 1, j + 1 );
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public Collection<List<T>> permutations( List<T> list, int size ) {
    Collection<List<T>> all = Lists.newArrayList();
    if ( list.size() < size ) {
      size = list.size();
    }
    if ( list.size() == size ) {
      all.addAll( Collections2.permutations( list ) );
    } else {
      for ( List<T> p : processSubsets( list, size ) ) {
        all.addAll( Collections2.permutations( p ) );
      }
    }
    return all;
  }
}
```

A special mention goes to [meriton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183406/meriton) whose answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504974/how-to-iteratively-generate-k-elements-subsets-from-a-set-of-size-n-in-java) helped me work it out.

Comment: Hi mrswadge, thanks for the detailed input ! Though your Java skills are way greater than mine and I'm unable to modify your code so I only get the following list : [[A, B, C], [A, B, D], [A, C, D], [B, C, D]] ;).

Comment: Ah, sorry - I see what you mean! I just re-read your question.

Change the method processSubsets( list, size ) to public. Call that instead of the method permutations( List<T> list, int size ). 

Job done :)

Comment: Wonderful, I think I fully understand your solution now. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in Guava feature that does this, though you could [submit a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list).

If I were writing an implementation, I *think* the simplest way would be to iterate through combinations (with [Gosper's hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications)), and then permutations of those with Collections2.permutations.

Alternately, it looks like some minor modifications to the normal permutation generation algorithm suffice, based on [this Python code](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll indeed submit a feature request for I believe such feature would be a valuable addition to Guava.

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to your question would be this:

```
public static <X> List<List<X>> test(List<X> input, final int n, final int m) {
    int x = 0;

    List<List<X>> newPerm = Lists.newArrayList();
    Collection<List<X>> perm = Collections2.permutations(input);
    for (Iterator<List<X>> it = perm.iterator(); it.hasNext(); x++) {
        if (x >= n) {
            break;
        }

        List<X> list = it.next();
        newPerm.add(Lists.partition(list, m).get(0));
    }

    return newPerm;
}
```

and then:

```
    List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach");
    List<List<String>> answer = test(list, 4, 3);
    for (List<String> list1 : answer) {
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
```

But it takes only the first ones and not a specifically defined set, your probably better off following Louis's advice

Comment: So you are suggesting to generate all permutations and then throw away the unneeded ones? The complexity of that is appalling! Imagine a set with 1000 elements and a limit of 2. Run this Java code to see what you get: `System.out.println(Collections2.permutations(Ranges.closed(1, 1000).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers())).size())`

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, yeah I understand that, but as I said it is a direct solution to his problem, not necessarily a good/concrete one

Comment: a solution like this would probably make a good unit test for a more efficient version.