# Most optimal way to combine unique groups of size k from n that meet specific requirements

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I have been working on something the past few days that seems to be working as intended, however I am looking for ways to improve it.  I have a set of n items, and I need to put together groups of these items that MUST meet ALL of the following requirements:

- 2 items from Category A
- 2 items from Category B
- 2 items from Category C
- 2 Items from Category D
- 1 item from Category E

I am currently using the following recursive method to put my groups together and the *isValid()* method is being used to determine if the group meets the criteria.

```
void getGroups(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result) {
  if(len == 0) {
    Group group = new Group(Arrays.asList(result));
    if(group.isValid()) {
      validGroups.add(group);
      group.printGroup();
    }
    return;
  }
  for(int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length - len; i++) {
    result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
    getGroups(arr, len - 1, i + 1, result);
  }
}
```

I am able to see valid results get printed as the program runs, however the original size of items that I am working with can be well over 100 items.  This means there is a very large number of total possible groups that will be iterated through and a lot of times the program never actually completes.

I know that there are currently a bunch of wasted iterations, for example if at some point I detect a group is invalid because it has 3 items from Category A, I should be able to move on.  I am not sure if my current method with a few tweaks is the best way to go about this, or if I should separate the items into their respective groups first, and then from their put only valid combinations together.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to make the method a bit more simpler than my actual method.  My actual method takes in an array of Objects that I've created that contain their value along with their category.  I guess for the example we can assume that each category is represented by a list of Strings that it contains.  The method can be called like:

```
String[] items = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7",
                  "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11", "test12", "test13",
                  "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18"};      
getGroups(items, 9, 0, new String[9]);
```

EDIT2:

```
List<String> catA = new     ArrayList<String>();
catA.add("test1");
catA.add("test2");
catA.add("test3");
catA.add("test4");

List<String> catB = new ArrayList<String>();
catB.add("test5");
catB.add("test6");
catB.add("test7");
catB.add("test8");

List<String> catC = new ArrayList<String>();
catC.add("test9");
catC.add("test10");
catC.add("test11");
catC.add("test12");

List<String> catS = new ArrayList<String>();
catD.add("test13");
catD.add("test14");
catD.add("test15");
catD.add("test16");

List<String> catE = new ArrayList<String>();
catE.add("test17");
catE.add("test18");
```

Output:

```
{"test1", "test2", "test5", "test6", "test9", "test10", "test13", "test14", "test17"}
{"test1", "test2", "test5", "test6", "test9", "test10", "test13", "test14", "test18"}
{"test1", "test2", "test5", "test6", "test9", "test10", "test13", "test16", "test17"}
{"test1", "test2", "test5", "test6", "test9", "test10", "test13", "test15", "test17"}
{"test1", "test2", "test5", "test6", "test9", "test10", "test14", "test15", "test17"}
```

etc...

Comment: I can't get any semantics out of that method, could you illustrate with some sample input?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I guess ideally I will have a list of valid groups along with each valid group getting printed to a log.  I tried to make the example simpler than the problem is.

Comment: I have no idea what you would expect as output for the input you gave us. Could you maybe post an actual minimal example?

Comment: Are the criteria going to change? Can we separate the items into their groups to start with and select?

Comment: I will try to post an expected output and more clarification once I get back to my computer.

Comment: The criteria would not change. I could just as easily populate one list with all items as I could 5 separate lists by category. The approach would be different going that route though and I actually tried coming up with a solution that way without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not write code but will list a possible approach. I say possible because it will be running and storing all data in memory and is not the best in regard to algorithms. yet, it is an approach where you don't need to eliminate invalid options. I will use an example in order to make things more clear.

suppose you have categories A,B,C. Where K=2 for A,B and K=1 for C.
you also have the input items A1,B1,B2,A2,C1,A3

1- go over the items and divide them according to their category. so you prepare an array/list for each category that has all the items that belong to it.

so now you have arrays:

Category A = [A1,A2,A3] , Category B = [B1,B2] and Category C=[C1]

2- now after preparing the lists, prepare the various legal groups that you can have for picking K items from N items found in that list . here is a link that might help in doing that efficiently: [How to iteratively generate k elements subsets from a set of size n in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504974/how-to-iteratively-generate-k-elements-subsets-from-a-set-of-size-n-in-java)

now you have:

first group belonging to category A: 
[A1,A2] , [A1,A3], [A2,A3] (3 elements)

second group belonging to category B:
[B1,B2] (1 element)

third group belonging to category C:
[C1]    (1 element)

3- now, if you treat each such group as an item, the question transforms to how many different ways are there for picking exactly one element from each group. and that is supposed to be easier to program recursively and will not require eliminating options. and if the number of categories is constant, it will be nested loops over the sets of groups in second point above.

**EDIT**

the approach works well in eliminating the need to validate bad combinations.
yet, there will still be a problem in regard of time. Here is the code that I made to demonstrate. it makes a list of 100 items. then it does the steps mentioned.
Note that I commented out the code that prints the groups.
The calculation is very fast up to that point. I have added code that prints how many legal choices can be made from each group.

```
package tester;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Tester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //generate 100 random items belonging to categories
       Random rand=new Random();
       List<Item> items=new ArrayList<>();
       int a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1;

       for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
          int randomNumber=rand.nextInt(5)+1;
          CATEGORY_TYPE categoryType=null;
          int num=0;
          switch (randomNumber) {
            case 1:
                categoryType=CATEGORY_TYPE.A;
                num=a++;
                break;

            case 2:
                categoryType=CATEGORY_TYPE.B;
                num=b++;
                break;

            case 3: 
                categoryType=CATEGORY_TYPE.C;
                num=c++;
                break;

            case 4: 
                categoryType=CATEGORY_TYPE.D;
                num=d++;
                break;

            case 5: 
                categoryType=CATEGORY_TYPE.E;
                num=e++;
                break;
          }

          String dummyData="Item "+categoryType.toString()+num;
          Item item=new Item(dummyData,categoryType); 
          items.add(item);
       }


       //arrange the items in lists by category 
       List<Item> categoryAItemsList=new ArrayList<>();
       List<Item> categoryBItemsList=new ArrayList<>();
       List<Item> categoryCItemsList=new ArrayList<>();
       List<Item> categoryDItemsList=new ArrayList<>();
       List<Item> categoryEItemsList=new ArrayList<>();
       for (Item item:items){
           if (item.getCategoryType()==CATEGORY_TYPE.A)
             categoryAItemsList.add(item);
           else if (item.getCategoryType()==CATEGORY_TYPE.B)
             categoryBItemsList.add(item);
           else if (item.getCategoryType()==CATEGORY_TYPE.C)
             categoryCItemsList.add(item);
           else if (item.getCategoryType()==CATEGORY_TYPE.D)
             categoryDItemsList.add(item);
           else if (item.getCategoryType()==CATEGORY_TYPE.E)
             categoryEItemsList.add(item);
       }


       //now we want to construct lists of possible groups of choosing from each category
       List<Item[]> subsetStoringListA=new ArrayList<>(); 
       List<Item[]> subsetStoringListB=new ArrayList<>(); 
       List<Item[]> subsetStoringListC=new ArrayList<>(); 
       List<Item[]> subsetStoringListD=new ArrayList<>(); 
       List<Item[]> subsetStoringListE=new ArrayList<>(); 


       processSubsets(categoryAItemsList.toArray(new Item[0]),2,subsetStoringListA); 
       processSubsets(categoryBItemsList.toArray(new Item[0]),2,subsetStoringListB);
       processSubsets(categoryCItemsList.toArray(new Item[0]),2,subsetStoringListC);
       processSubsets(categoryDItemsList.toArray(new Item[0]),2,subsetStoringListD);
       processSubsets(categoryEItemsList.toArray(new Item[0]),1,subsetStoringListE);

       System.out.println(" A groups number: "+subsetStoringListA.size());
       System.out.println(" B groups number: "+subsetStoringListB.size());
       System.out.println(" C groups number: "+subsetStoringListC.size());
       System.out.println(" D groups number: "+subsetStoringListD.size());
       System.out.println(" E groups number: "+subsetStoringListE.size());

       //now we just print all possible combinations of picking a single group from each list.
       //the group is an array with valid choices
//       for (Item[] subsetA:subsetStoringListA){
//         for (Item[] subsetB:subsetStoringListB){
//            for (Item[] subsetC:subsetStoringListC){
//                for (Item[] subsetD:subsetStoringListD){
//                    for (Item[] subsetE:subsetStoringListE){
//                        print(subsetA);
//                        print(subsetB);
//                        print(subsetC);
//                        print(subsetD);
//                        print(subsetE);
//                        System.out.println("\n");
//                    }
//                    
//                }
//            } 
//         }  
//       }


    }


    static void print(Item[] arr){
      for (Item item:arr)  
        System.out.print(item.getDumyData()+" "); 
    }

    static void processSubsets(Item[] set, int k,List<Item[]> subsetStoringList) {
    Item[] subset = new Item[k];
    processLargerSubsets(set, subset, 0, 0,subsetStoringList);
}

static void processLargerSubsets(Item[] set, Item[] subset, int subsetSize, int nextIndex,List<Item[]> subsetStoringList) {
    if (subsetSize == subset.length) { //here we have a subset we need to store a copy from it
        subsetStoringList.add(Arrays.copyOf(subset, subset.length));
    } else {
        for (int j = nextIndex; j < set.length; j++) {
            subset[subsetSize] = set[j];
            processLargerSubsets(set, subset, subsetSize + 1, j + 1,subsetStoringList);
        }
    }
}


    public static enum CATEGORY_TYPE {A,B,C,D,E} 

    private static class Item{
        private CATEGORY_TYPE categoryType;
        private String dumyData; 

        public Item(String dumyData,CATEGORY_TYPE categoryType) {
            this.dumyData = dumyData; //maybe bad name but i mean the object can have many other fields etc
            this.categoryType = categoryType;
        }

        /**
         * @return the categoryType
         */
        public CATEGORY_TYPE getCategoryType() {
            return categoryType;
        }

        /**
         * @return the dumyData
         */
        public String getDumyData() {
            return dumyData;
        }


    }



}
```

in a specific run, it gave the following:

A groups number: 210
B groups number: 153
C groups number: 210
D groups number: 210
E groups number: 19

that means , if we had to print all possible choices of a single element (and here an elemnt is an array containing k choices from a category) from each of these, you will have : 210*153*210*210*19 = 26,921,727,000
now listing/printing over 26 billion variations will take time no matter what and I don't see how it will be minimized.

try setting the total items to 20 and uncomment the printing code to see that everything is working correctly. And see if you really need to list the possible combinations. please remember that every combination here is legal and there are no wasted iterations in all the parts of the code. 
one final note: I did not treat edge cases like when there are no items in a category to complete K. that you can easily put in the code according to the desired behaviour in that case.

Comment: This is very similar to the original approach I took to solving this problem, however I kept running out of memory.  I will try to revisit this method if I am unable to implement the one above.  Thank you.

Comment: This should be the best approach for this problem. Just one improvement for the memory problem, you don't need to generate every possible combinations first, you can take first combination in Group A, then first combination in Group B, then iterate over combinations of Group C.

Comment: I have successfully implemented this approach, however I started running it last night and it's still going 6 hours later.  Seems to be working about as well as my original solution, but still taking too long.

Comment: can you post the data that you used (overrwiting any important data) and the code you made for this approach in a place where we can obtain it? even if this is not the best approach, it is still interesting for me to see why it takes so long.

Comment: also, is the number of categories constant like stated in the question? or it can change ?

Comment: The number of categories is constant, however the number of items in each category is not.

Comment: I will definitely take a look at your edit once I get some more time today.  At a quick look, it seems like our approach is very similar though my sets are much larger.  A Groups: 861, B Groups: 946, C Groups: 703, D Groups: 903, E Groups: 31

Comment: the groups size depends also on input data. in any case note what I wrote in the end of the edit regarding number of variations.

Comment: Our implementations were nearly identical.  I have it running now without any printing at all just to see how long it takes to complete.  Unfortunately it seems like there's no way around the issue considering how large the sets I am working with are.

Comment: I am trying to think of a more optimal way to combine the lists other than the nested for loops.  Any ideas?  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: check my details and contact me on my e-mail if you wish. and you are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

I use a `BitPattern` iterator I wrote a while ago that walks all n-bit numbers containing just k set bits and uses that to select from your categories.

Note that much of this code is building the test data to reflect your requirements.

I hold a `List` of `Iterable`s which are the `BitPattern`s. A list of `Iterator`s which are the currently in-use `Iterator`s from the `BitPattern`s (they must be renewed every time they complete) and a `List` of `BigIntger`s that are the current values to explode into selections from the data.

```
public class Test {

  enum Category {

    A(2), B(2), C(2), D(2), E(1);
    public final int required;

    Category(int required) {
      this.required = required;
    }
  }

  private static final Category[] categories = Category.values();

  static class Categorised {

    final String name;
    final Category category;

    Categorised(String name, Category category) {
      this.name = name;
      this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return category.name() + ":" + name;
    }
  }

  static final List<Categorised> data = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    data.add(new Categorised("A-1", Category.A));
    data.add(new Categorised("A-2", Category.A));
    data.add(new Categorised("A-3", Category.A));
    data.add(new Categorised("B-1", Category.B));
    data.add(new Categorised("B-2", Category.B));
    data.add(new Categorised("B-3", Category.B));
    data.add(new Categorised("C-1", Category.C));
    data.add(new Categorised("C-2", Category.C));
    data.add(new Categorised("C-3", Category.C));
    data.add(new Categorised("D-1", Category.D));
    data.add(new Categorised("D-2", Category.D));
    data.add(new Categorised("D-3", Category.D));
    data.add(new Categorised("E-1", Category.E));
    data.add(new Categorised("E-2", Category.E));
    data.add(new Categorised("E-3", Category.E));
  }

  // Categorise the data.
  private Map<Category, List<Categorised>> categorise(List<Categorised> data) {
    Map<Category, List<Categorised>> categorised = new EnumMap<>(Category.class);
    for (Categorised d : data) {
      List<Categorised> existing = categorised.get(d.category);
      if (existing == null) {
        existing = new ArrayList<>();
        categorised.put(d.category, existing);
      }
      existing.add(d);
    }
    return categorised;
  }

  public void test() {
    // Categorise the data.
    Map<Category, List<Categorised>> categorised = categorise(data);
    // Build my lists.
    // A source of Iteratprs.
    List<BitPattern> is = new ArrayList<>(categories.length);
    // The Iterators.
    List<Iterator<BigInteger>> its = new ArrayList<>(categories.length);
    // The current it patterns to use to select.
    List<BigInteger> next = new ArrayList<>(categories.length);
    for (Category c : categories) {
      int k = c.required;
      List<Categorised> from = categorised.get(c);
      // ToDo - Make sure there are enough.
      int n = from.size();
      // Make my iterable.
      BitPattern p = new BitPattern(k, n);
      is.add(p);
      // Gather an Iterator.
      Iterator<BigInteger> it = p.iterator();
      // Store it.
      its.add(it);
      // Prime it.
      next.add(it.next());
    }
    // Walk the lists.
    boolean stepped;
    do {
      // Interpret the current numbers.
      List<Categorised> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
      for ( int c = 0; c < categories.length; c++ ) {
        BigInteger b = next.get(c);
        List<Categorised> category = categorised.get(categories[c]);
        // Step through the bits in the number.
        BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(b.toByteArray());
        for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
          // Pull those entries from the categorised list.
          candidates.add(category.get(i));
        }
      }
      // Print it for now.
      System.out.println(candidates);
      // Step again.
      stepped = step(is, its, next);
    } while (stepped);
  }

  // Take one step.
  private boolean step(List<BitPattern> is, List<Iterator<BigInteger>> its, List<BigInteger> next) {
    boolean stepped = false;
    // Step each one until we make one successful step.
    for (int i = 0; i < is.size() && !stepped; i++) {
      Iterator<BigInteger> it = its.get(i);
      if (it.hasNext()) {
        // Done here!
        stepped = true;
      } else {
        // Exhausted - Reset it.
        its.set(i, it = is.get(i).iterator());
      }
      // Pull that one.
      next.set(i, it.next());
    }
    return stepped;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

This is the `BitPattern` iterator.

```
/**
 * Iterates all bit patterns containing the specified number of bits.
 *
 * See "Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation"
 * http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class BitPattern implements Iterable<BigInteger> {
  // Useful stuff.
  private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
  private static final BigInteger TWO = ONE.add(ONE);
  // How many bits to work with.
  private final int bits;
  // Value to stop at. 2^max_bits.
  private final BigInteger stop;
  // Should we invert the output.
  private final boolean not;

  // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits - invberting if required.
  public BitPattern(int bits, int max, boolean not) {
    this.bits = bits;
    this.stop = TWO.pow(max);
    this.not = not;
  }

  // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits.
  public BitPattern(int bits, int max) {
    this(bits, max, false);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
    return new BitPatternIterator();
  }

  /*
   * From the link:
   * 
   * Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and 
   * we want the next permutation of N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense. 
   * 
   * For example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011, the next patterns would be 
   * 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,
   * 00011010, 00011100, 00100011, 
   * and so forth. 
   * 
   * The following is a fast way to compute the next permutation. 
   */
  private class BitPatternIterator implements Iterator<BigInteger> {
    // Next to deliver - initially 2^n - 1
    BigInteger next = TWO.pow(bits).subtract(ONE);
    // The last one we delivered.
    BigInteger last;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (next == null) {
        // Next one!
        // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
        // unsigned int t = v | (v - 1); 
        BigInteger t = last.or(last.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        // Silly optimisation.
        BigInteger notT = t.not();
        // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change, 
        // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
        // w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
        // The __builtin_ctz(v) GNU C compiler intrinsic for x86 CPUs returns the number of trailing zeros.
        next = t.add(ONE).or(notT.and(notT.negate()).subtract(ONE).shiftRight(last.getLowestSetBit() + 1));
        if (next.compareTo(stop) >= 0) {
          // Dont go there.
          next = null;
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger next() {
      last = hasNext() ? next : null;
      next = null;
      return not ? last.not(): last;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
      return next != null ? next.toString(2) : last != null ? last.toString(2): "";
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly my idea! =D

Comment: I am definitely making some progress with this approach, however I seem to be getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Trying to figure out why that is happening right now.  Is it worth noting that the number of items in each category will almost never be the same size?

Comment: @ThomasMancini - Sorry to hear that - where is the Exception being thrown? Are you sure there are enough items in the data to satisfy the limits? If there is not then that could certainly cause issues - See my *ToDo* comment.

Comment: @ThomasMancini - The number of items in each category should not affect the outcome - other than affecting how many solutions there are.

Comment: @ThomasMancini - I have confirmed that if the categories state that there must be *n* of a particular category and the data does not provide at least *n* items to fill that requirement then an *IndexOutOfBoundsException* will be thrown on the `candidates.add(category.get(i));` line. That situation should be checked for (where I have the *ToDo* comment) and rejected as insoluble.

Comment: There are definitely more than enough categories to satisfy the requirements.  I did not originally see that ToDo as Eclipse only highlights the syntax for TODO.  Sorry about that.  I added a check there just in case, but still have the same issue.  It's always on the size of the first category's group, so: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 42, Size: 42`.  This is the size of the number of items in Category A.

Comment: @ThomasMancini - I guess you are requesting 43 Category A items in your selection and there are less than that in your data. I can reproduce your problem in my code by using `A(4), B(2), C(2), D(2), E(1);`. There are only 3 Category A items in my data.

Comment: First, I would like to say tyvm for your continued assistance here.  I have the enum set up as A(2), B(2), C(2), D(2), E(1).  And there are the following number of items in each category respectively: 42, 44, 38, 43, and 31.  Maybe I messed something up along the way using my own data structures?  I added a count inside of the `for ( int c = 0; c < categories.length; c++ ) {` loop and this gets to 3715 before getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to be a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). So maybe try [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)?
I believe the following works, but plug in your own data to guaranteee.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Launch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Formulate the constraints.
        int[] constraints = { 2, 1, 0, 1 };

        // Create all the items.
        List<boolean[]> items = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
        boolean[] i1 = { true, false, true, false };
        boolean[] i2 = { true, false, false, false };
        boolean[] i3 = { false, true, false, true };
        boolean[] i4 = { false, false, false, true };
        items.add(i1);
        items.add(i2);
        items.add(i3);
        items.add(i4);

        // Solve!
        backtrack(constraints, items);
    }

    /**
     * Recursively generate possible solutions but backtrack as soon as the constraints fail.
     */
    private static void backtrack(int[] constraints, List<boolean[]> items) {
        // We start with no items belonging to any categories.
        List<List<boolean[]>> memberships = new ArrayList<List<boolean[]>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
            memberships.add(new ArrayList<boolean[]>());
        }

        backtrack(constraints, items, memberships);
    }

    /**
     * Recursively generate possible solutions but backtrack as soon as the constraints fail.
     */
    private static void backtrack(int[] constraints, List<boolean[]> items,
            List<List<boolean[]>> memberships) {
        if (items.isEmpty() && !acceptable(constraints, memberships)) {
            return;
        } else if (acceptable(constraints, memberships)) {
            display(memberships);
        } else {
            for (boolean[] item : items) {
                int catIdx = 0;
                for (boolean belongs : item) {
                    if (belongs) {
                        // The item and category were chosen so let's update
                        // memberships.
                        List<List<boolean[]>> newMemberships = new ArrayList<List<boolean[]>>();
                        for (List<boolean[]> old : memberships) {
                            newMemberships.add(new ArrayList<boolean[]>(old));
                        }
                        newMemberships.get(catIdx).add(item);

                        // We've placed the item so let's remove it from the
                        // possibilities.
                        List<boolean[]> newItems = new ArrayList<boolean[]>(
                                items);
                        newItems.remove(item);

                        // Now solve the sub-problem.
                        backtrack(constraints, newItems, newMemberships);
                    }
                    catIdx++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * A nice way to display the membership tables.
     */
    private static void display(List<List<boolean[]>> memberships) {
        System.out.println("---");
        for (List<boolean[]> category : memberships) {          
            for (boolean[] item : category) {
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(item) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not a list of memberships are accepted by the
     * constraints.
     * 
     * @param constraints
     *            - The number of items required per category.
     * @param memberships
     *            - The current items per category.
     */
    private static boolean acceptable(int[] constraints,
            List<List<boolean[]>> memberships) {
        boolean acceptable = memberships.size() == constraints.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < memberships.size(); i++) {
            acceptable = acceptable
                    && constraints[i] == memberships.get(i).size();
        }
        return acceptable;
    }

}
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried taking this approach.  I am assuming my constraints array is how many from each group I would want.  So I am using int[] constraints = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1}; .  I am getting a little caught up on the following loop in the second backtrack method.  
    for (boolean belongs : item) {
      if (belongs) {
Since my arrays are not of booleans, what would I be checking in here?

Comment: @ThomasMancini It's basically: `for each category, if this item belongs to that category, ...`. (I wasn't sure if an item could belong to more than one category.)

Comment: I figured it was something like that although I already have the categories separated at this point, so I know all items in each array belong in that respective category.

Comment: @ThomasMancini I think I have misread the problem. This solution might be incorrect and/or overkill.